# Selenium server standalone for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, selenium

I'm using selenium server standalone to run some selenium tests on Internet explorer but it opens an embedded Internet Explorer which has 2 drowbacks

1. my sites renders differently (every thing is good in IE but not in embedded IE)
2. it does not use internet explorer settings so even while I've turned off script debugging in IE I still get some errors in Embedded IE.

anybody has any idea how can i make selenium standalone server to work with IE, not Embedded IE?
I use latest version of both server and driver which is 2.44

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have any OS restrictions and your Selenium Server can be executed in a Windows-based machine, why not use the Internet Explorer Driver Server for your IE-specific tests instead?

One advantage as per Wiki is that - *Runs in a real browser and supports Javascript*

And if you decide to, try running down thru each of the required configuration for the InternetExplorerDriver in the Wiki:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

**Required Configuration**

The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH.

- On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the
  Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value
  can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set
  the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the
  Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will
  be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected
  Mode".
- Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10
  and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet
  Options dialog.
- The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse
  events can be set to the correct coordinates.
- For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
  computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
  of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations,
  the key you must examine in the registry editor is
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
  installations, the key is
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
  FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
  created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
  DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.